# Generate java classes to src not only to target with maven cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have written a .wsdl file and now want to generate source code from it with maven. I have add to maven this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>\src\main\java\wsdlgenerated</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>\src\main\resources\wsdl\myWsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

when I run `maven clean install` then the code is generated only to `target` folder no to the `src`.

Comment: It is strongly recommended _not_ to generate anything to `src` inside a build. These classes will otherwise _not_ be cleaned and might checked into source control accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

try this tags  ${basedir} and ${project.build.directory} to generate classes in src folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: sourceRoot should be:  with `${basedir}` then it works for me

Comment: Can you please enable the debug log and check the exact location path for generated classe using         mvn clean install  -X